# Looking for software that has a shopping cart where I can sell licensed photos

Tags: looking-for-a-script, shopping-cart, photo-gallery, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online Shopping Cart Solutions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/online-shopping-cart-solutions)

I'm in need of a shopping cart that I can sell licensed photos. I know some carts like Magento support downloadable products, but its not really optimized for photos. I was wonder if anyone knows of a good solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be what you are looking for: http://www.picturespro.com/i/photo_cart/

It isn't free, so if you were hoping to avoid buying something, this may not be up your alley.

If this doesn't work for you, try googling "photo shopping cart". There are other options out there.