# Online E-Commerce Solutions - What To Look For?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, ecommerce, shopping-cart

In Today's market many shopping carts and ecommerce solutions are available on the web.

What are the essential features someone looking to start an online store should look for before choosing software?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Because this question is open ended and based on opinion I have converted this question to community wiki.  Please read the FAQ, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq, for more info on what that means and to see what kinds of questions are appropriate for our site.  We would also appreciate if you modified your question to be slightly more specific.  Is there a specific platform or programming language you want your shopping cart to work in?  Please let us know if you have questions about what is appropriate.

Comment: You might want to ask this question to stackoverflow but I am sure this kinds of question is asked many times there and you will hopefully find a answer there. You still have to provide the information what kinds of site you need.