# Small, fast shopping cart setup

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, payments, shopping-cart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online E-Commerce Solutions - What To Look For?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/online-e-commerce-solutions-what-to-look-for)

I'm looking for an open source shopping cart solution that's simple and easy to setup. The requirements are:

- Quick setup for someone familiar with *nix webservers.
- Checkout via PayPal (other payment methods not needed).
- Customers should not have to create an account to make a purchase.
- At least a minimal level of inventory control.
- Ability to print/export a list of orders in compact form.

Any recommendations for something I should try? Ability to get it up and working quickly is really my priority right now; if it's not ideal, it can be replaced (or, as I'm looking for open source, I can adapt it to fit the requirements better) at a later time.

**Edit:** Really what I'm looking for is simplicity. This will be for a small local business, and the orders will consist of 1-10 items that are being delivered by a driver who needs a simple list of what each customer received when making delivery. Looking like a giant online computer/electronics/etc. store is definitely not a desirable quality. The simpler the interface presented to customers (who are used to purchasing through dumb web forms and paying COD), the better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to osCommerce (http://www.oscommerce.com/) and OpenCart (http://www.opencart.com)

Comment: I looked at it, and it seems nice but way beyond the scale I need. Updating question...

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, i think prestashop rock very solid at this ! 
I was using OScommerce and magento until i tried prestashop for a client :-)

OSCommerce is a little bit buggy espacially if you have to deal with multiple currencies/taxes etc ..

Magento is very "heavy" and complexe for out of the box online shops.

Prestashop is beautiful, work well, clear instructions, easy to install and very easy to use. I recommand it !

Other ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040472/prestashop-compared-to-zen-cart-and-oscommerce

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.mals-e.com/ it's pretty basic and free

Comment: Interesting but this looks like a service rather than software...?

Comment: It's managed through their site, you just copy and paste the HTML but has some good features for a free hosted cart. I used them quite a few years ago. You can also check out CS-Cart community edition it's a free version of their cart with all the basics you'll need to run a shop

Comment: Yes, it looks really nice, but I'm reluctant to use or recommend anything that's hosted where you don't have the software on your server and under your control. If it goes down, gets shut down (unfairly) due to criminals using it, gets "upgraded" in a way that breaks something you're doing or just confuses your customers, etc. that's all really catastrophic from a business standpoint... It looks like a great product, if it were a product and not a service... :(

Comment: In that case to host your own software and not worry about being shutdown, then download cs-cart community edition and give it a try, you can install with demo data to play around with it.