# Suggestions required to build an ECommerce Platform

Tags: shopping-cart, customer-service, crm

For a prospective client we have to offer a solution to provide following system:

- CMS
- Order Management
- Shopping Cart
- CRM
- Helpdesk
- Accounting & Finance
- Custom Functions

In order to save time and to avoid reinvent the wheel our idea is to integrate different off-the-shelf solutions. Their first requirement is that the system has to be hosted in their country which I think will exclude application like Aplicor, Netsuite & Salesforce.

Basically the nucleaus would be the CMS which would integrate all the other apps.

PHP or .Net based solutions would be our preferences as have inhouse expertise.

So far following are few combinations I have come up with:

- Joomla (CMS) + Virtuemart (Cart+Ordering) + Sugar CRM + Open ERP (finance) + OTRS
- Magento (CMS+Cart+Ordering) + Sugar CRM + Open ERP (finance) + Helpdesk Ultimate
- Drupal (CMS) + Ubercart (Cart+Ordering) + Sugar CRM + Open ERP (finance) + Support Ticketing System
- Sharepoint (CMS) + OptimusBt (Cart+Ordering) + Dynamics CRM + Great Plains + SharepointHQ
- Dotnetnuke (CMS) + DNNSpot (Cart+Ordering) + Sigma Pro (CRM+Helpdesk) + Open ERP

For Helpdesk I liked Zendesk but the server location was the stopping factor, similar for finance and CRM I liked Aplicor.

I would not like to go into detailed requirements as it would make things very complex.

Could you please suggest me which options are worth enough to start looking into? What other options we have?

Comment: Polling questions are not a good fit for the [StackExchange Q&A format](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) - could you revise your question into a practical, answerable form? (e.g. "Does this combination of software support my list of requirements?")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online Shopping Cart Solutions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/online-shopping-cart-solutions)

Answer (score 0):

We use Magento a lot and it is a little complicated but worth it. Just be aware that it uses more resources than other systems. I would recommend it to you as well because it already solves 3 of your problems.

We use Sugar CRM internally and are happy with it. But I don't know if it fits your needs. There is a [Zenddesk Plugin for Sugar CRM](https://support.zendesk.com/entries/20098557-zendesk-for-sugarcrm-getting-started). I know that this is not possible for you but I just wanted to mention it. So you are aware that the are probably other helpdesk modules available.

Regarding ERP I can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are far better off spending money to have custom modules developed for Magento rather than starting from scratch. Consider how much you'd be spending to simply integrate with a payment gateway plus paypal. Then you have to manage ever response from the gateways etc. I would look at integrating Magento and SalesForce which is already possible.